# How can non-Coinbase customers pay to Coinbase from Android?

Tags: coinbase.com, android, shopping-cart-interface

Scenario: Say I want to create a shopping app on android. After filling the shopping cart, when the user wants to check out, he is asked to pay me the bitcoins.

I have created an account on Coinbase.com.

Questions: After adding the items in the app to the cart, the user is directed to the coinbase payment page. How is the user going to pay me, if he doesn't have a Coinbase account but some other wallet? If he pays me the required bitcoins, how will I relate the user's payment with the invoice of the order generated for him?

Comment: Hi srujan, I tried to refactor your question to make it a bit more succinct, and easier to understand your topic from the title and tags. I hope I managed to conserve your intent. Should I have changed your question in a way that you feel is inappropriate please feel free to make any ammendments or roll-back my changes.

Answer (score 2):

The coinbase payment page has a "pay to address" option that will generate a unique address associated with your order and display a QR code. User can simply send payment to that address.

Comment: After the user proceeds with payment, say with his coinbase account then the coinbase will understand that the payment has been done, but if the user uses another vendor say gocoin then will the coinbase acknowledges the transfer for the particular invoice?

Comment: Yes because the address he pays to is uniquely generated for that particular invoice only.